# object reference and garbage collection

Tags: java, jvm

when the code has below relationship, will B and C will be garbage collected if disconnect A from B? and why?thanks

```
class A{
    B b;
    A(B b);
}

class B{
    C c;
    B(C c);
}

class C{
    C();
}

class TestTarget{
    public void test{
    c = new C;
    b = new B(c);
    a = new A(b); 
    a = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't compile, so it's safe to say that nothing will happen at all.

Comment: this is general code to describe the relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a working code of the above scenario exist then Yes B and C will be collected by GC. As there is no outgoing reference from C and no Incoming reference to B but there exist relationship between B and C. So GC will not collect the objects of B and C immediately. After threshold number of GC cycles these  object will be collected.

Answer (score 1):

Objects of C and B will be GC. if you take heap dump  after a is set to NULL. The heapdump will have the objects of B and C but if you exclude soft/weak/phantom reference of these object then you can't see any strong refernces which means these objects are eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you are asking about *composition* and GC i.e, `A` has `B` and `B` has `C` then, when you set `instanceOfA==null`, `instanceOfA` , `instanceOfB` and `instanceOfC` will be *eligible for GC* provided they are not referenced from anywhere (Assuming references have not *leaked*)

Answer (score 0):

No they won't be garbage collected, because you still have other live variables that point to them. 
If you set them to null as well (b = null, c=null) they can be garbage collected.